# How to make my local SQL Server database case sensitive in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database, case-sensitive, vs-web-site-project

I have a database in my asp.net web project. I'm using SSDT for Visual Studio 2015 to add local database to my web project. I have tables and stored procedures in my database `_logdb`.

My problem is this my database isn't 'case sensitive' and it isn't distinguishing b/w upper, lower or camel case due to this I'm facing some problem in ADO.NET coding. When I see the property of database it showing that "case sensitive :False".

Can anyone tell me how can I make my database case sensitive?

property of my db

[image]

I have read out many post regarding my problem but nothing helped and I'm new here so if I missed anything please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the instance collation which would require dropping the databases before changing it. [Here is a link to setting or changing the Server Collation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-server-collation)

You can also do this on a database level. [Here is information on setting or changing collation on the database level.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/set-or-change-the-database-collation)

You may also want to read [the collation clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations) which can also be applied to tables, columns, and casting expressions among additional options.

Comment: I believe you can set this **on a per-database level**, too - not just the instance/server level ....

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried `ALTER DATABASE "db-name" COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS`?

Answer (score 0):

The database collation setting controls case sensitivity in SQL Server.  When using a SQL Server database project in Visual Studio, you can select the desired database collation by opening the database project's Properties tab and then, on the Project Settings page, clicking on the Database Settings button.